# returned "Insufficient Permission"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-admin-sdk

```
class DirectoryV1Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @decorator.oauth_required
  def get(self):
    https = httplib2.Http()
    https = decorator.credentials.authorize(https)
    #service = build('directory', 'v1', http=https)
    service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=https, developerKey="YOUR-API-CONSOLE-KEY")
    #json.dumps(service)
    logging.info(service.userphoto().get(userKey='userKey'))
    user = service.userphoto().get(userKey='userKey').execute()
    logging.info(user)
```

When running the above I get the following error, please provide help:
`HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{userKey}?alt=json&key="YOUR-API-CONSOLE-KEY" returned "Insufficient Permission"`

Comment: well 403 says it all, you dont have permission for that resource.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace YOUR-API-CONSOLE-KEY with the key found in APIs Console